# how I can remove the keyboard that appears automatically onCreate?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an edit text with custom keyboard or numpad my problem is when I open my app the android keyboard appears automatically I don't want for that to happen
my apps idea is simple when i click on edit text my custom keyboard appears .
so how I can remove the android keyboard that appears at the first 
by the way if i cancel  it manually in the app it never shows up but as i say on reopen the app appears again please help

[image]

[image]

```
public class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements OnKeyboardActionListener {

private Activity mTargetActivity;

/***
 * 
 * @param targetActivity
 *            Activity a cui deve essere girato l'evento
 *            "pressione di un tasto sulla tastiera"
 */
public BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(Activity targetActivity) {
    mTargetActivity = targetActivity;
}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

    mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

CustomKeyboardView.class

```
public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {

public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void showWithAnimation(Animation animation) {
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    setAnimation(animation);
}
```

KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity.class

```
public class KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity extends Activity {

private CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
private View mTargetView;
private Keyboard mKeyboard;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
    mTargetView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    mTargetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Dobbiamo intercettare l'evento onTouch in modo da aprire la
            // nostra tastiera e prevenire che venga aperta quella di
            // Android
            showKeyboardWithAnimation();
            return true;
        }
    });

    mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
    mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
    mKeyboardView
            .setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(
                    this));
}

/***
 * Mostra la tastiera a schermo con una animazione di slide dal basso
 */
private void showKeyboardWithAnimation() {
    if (mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils
                .loadAnimation(KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity.this,
                        R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
        mKeyboardView.showWithAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

this is the main xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/keyboard_view">
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/target"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<it.anddev.tutorial.CustomKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view" android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></it.anddev.tutorial.CustomKeyboardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just define that code in the manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".activity.HomeScreen"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Hope this help you..

Comment: thanks for the help can u help me with simple thing
i want the right button at the bottom to be enter or done button when i press it  not to go new line just like done button what is the code rather than 66 and when i press the number i don't want this white highlights to appear or the logos

Comment: you want to go the next edit text on the done button or want new line in the same edittext

Comment: yea it is like that but i dont have any new edit text

Comment: just want to enter the number like saving it

Comment: and how i can remove the white blank highlights just the ones with pictures appears but the numbers shows blank white i don't want this thing at all for all the buttons

Comment: try this one :-
mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);

Answer (score 1):

Add a new class Utilities.java include the below code

```
public static void hideKeypad(Context context, View edit) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edit.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

then call the below code in which class you want to hide the keyboard

**Utilities.hideKeypad(thisActivity, txtName);**

Example:

txtName --> you can pass your Edittext variable here

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: which class should i put this ?

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: which class should i put this ?

Comment: On your onCreate() in KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity.class

Comment: wherever your first event is happening and keyboard is popping up

Comment: <activity android:name=".KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
This can also help :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used following code for this problem earlier:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

use this on `onCreate()`

Comment: which class should i put this ?

Comment: in class `KeyboardWidgetTutorialActivity ` under `onCreate` method

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the keyboard for your activity in Manifest file by adding line below to corresponding activity tag:

```
<activity android:name="packageName.ActivityName"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below line of code in your Linear Layout

```
android:focusable="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this method and just call it from onCreate():

```
private void hideSoftKeyBoard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if(imm.isAcceptingText()) { // verify if the soft keyboard is open                      
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to LinearLayout to remove focus from EditText.